# How do I use $(this) in a jQuery hover event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have hidden an unordered list within a div. The div has a class '.feed-label' and I'm currently showing the ul when the div is hovered over.

My problem is that when hovered over, all the other elements are also showing and I want only the one which was hovered over to show.

I don't know how to use $(this).

```
$('.feed-label').hover(function() {
    $('.article-interactive-buttons').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: If you're trying to toggle an element within the hovered element you could do `$(this).find(selector).toggleClass('hide');`

Comment: the ul is already hidden using the class hide, toggleClass is adding and removing it on hover

Comment: If you could provide the html, there might be a css only solution, if you would like to go for one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword in the context of the event handler refers to the hovered element, i.e. the `.feed-label` element. You should create a jQuery object by passing the element to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) constructor and then use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method for selecting the target descendant.

```
$('.feed-label').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.article-interactive-buttons').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

You could also use the [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) syntax which will work like the above snippet:

```
$('.feed-label').hover(function() {
    $('.article-interactive-buttons', this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: Wow, I wonder how I missed the `selector, context` syntax all these years. thats awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If the ul is within the div, and you would like to go for a css only solution you could do this:

```
.feed-label:hover .article-interactive-buttons {
     display: none;
}

.feed-label:hover .article-interactive-buttons {
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
$('.feed-label').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.article-interactive     buttons').toggleClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's find instead of find. I misunderstand the question.